# Updating an Object in LocalStorage Using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

Edit - Updated JS code to display suggestions made in comments, still having issues.. Now the button `<input id="edit" type="submit" value="Submit">` won't go to `edit.html`, instead it is returning `action.html`? It is nested inside of the editForm?

I have a simple form which I have managed to learn to submit, add, remove, and display bookings using the `localStorage` (thanks to those who helped on here!).

My last task is to amend a booking, I think I am almost there with it, but not sure how to call the indexes (excuse my jargon), to replace the values.

The form submits and the web address reads something like `edit.html?OldFirstName=NewFirstName&OldLastName=NewLastName`, however the values don't update in storage, and it throws an error saying

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fname' of undefined`.
```

I expected this to happen as I know I am not finding the values correctly, but I can't figure out how I should be writing it out? My thought process was that it would be similar to the original submit function but with the `[i]` values for `fname` and `lname`?

Here's my JS code - if you need anything else from me let me know:

```
// ~~~ add bookings to localStorage

var bookings = localStorage.getItem("bookings");

$("#submit").click(function () {
    bookings = (bookings) ? JSON.parse(bookings) : [];

    var newBookings = { 
        fname: $('#fname').val(), 
        lname: $('#lname').val() 
    }

    bookings.push(newBookings);

    var json = JSON.stringify(bookings);
    window.localStorage.setItem("bookings", json);

});

// ~~~ edit bookings in localStorage

$("#edit").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    bookings = (bookings) ? JSON.parse(bookings) : [];

    var parent_form = $('#editForm');

    var fname = parent_form.find('.input:eq(0)').val();
    var lname = parent_form.find('.input:eq(1)').val();

    var newBookings = { 
        fname: fname, 
        lname: lname 
    }

    bookings.push(newBookings);

    var json = JSON.stringify(bookings);
    window.localStorage.setItem("bookings", json);

});


// ~~~ display bookings in browser

function showBooking(i) {
    var bookingResult = document.getElementById("result");
    var ul = document.createElement("ul");
    var bookingItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookings")) || [];
    bookingResult.innerHTML = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < bookingItems.length; i++) {
        bookingResult.innerHTML += `<div class="card card-body bg-light  m-4"> 
<h3>${bookingItems[i].fname + " " + bookingItems[i].lname} 
<button onclick="deleteBooking(${i})" class="btn btn-danger text-light ">Delete</button>
<button onclick="editBooking(${i})" class="btn btn-danger text-light ">Edit</button>
</h3>                            
</div>`;
    }
}

// ~~~ edit bookings in browser

function editBooking(i) {
    var bookingResult = document.getElementById("editAppt");
    var bookingItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookings")) || [];
    bookingResult.innerHTML = 
        `<form id="editForm" name="editForm" onsubmit="return editForm(this)" class="col-sm-6">
<div class="row">
<input type="text" class="input" id="fname_${i}" placeholder="${bookingItems[i].fname}" name="${bookingItems[i].fname}" required>
<input type="text" id="lname_${i}" class="input" placeholder="${bookingItems[i].lname}" name="${bookingItems[i].lname}" required>
<input id="edit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>

</form>`;
}

// ~~~ delete bookings from localStorage

function deleteBooking(i){
    var bookingItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookings"));
    bookingItems.splice(i, 1);
    localStorage.setItem("bookings", JSON.stringify(bookingItems));
    showBooking();
}

// ~~~ form submit handlers

function setAction(form) {
    form.action = "action.html";
}

function editForm(form) {
    form.action = "edit.html";
}
```

Comment: that code is crying out for encapsulating the booking database logic to separate it from the UI logic.

Comment: I will look into that, thanks @Alnitak

Answer (score 2):

I can see that the issue comes from this like :

```
$("#edit").click(function (i) {
```

You expect the click event to return an index but it's not, the `i` will represent the event object, so you may need to use `$(this)` to get the related inputs like :

```
$("#edit").click(function (e) {
    var parent_form = $(this.form);

    var fname = parent_form.find('.input:eq(0)').val();
    var lname = parent_form.find('.input:eq(1)').val();

    ....
```

**NOTE:** The id must not be duplicated, so you need to avoid that, you may use prefix like:

```
<input type="text" class="input" id="fname_${i}" placeholder="${bookingItems[i].fname}" name="${bookingItems[i].fname}" required>
<input type="text" class="input" id="lname_${i}" placeholder="${bookingItems[i].lname}" name="${bookingItems[i].lname}" required>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will go try this. My edit function has stopped working so I need to fix that first.

Comment: Unfortunately this makes no difference. I am not really understanding the `.input:eq(0)` part, could you explain?

Comment: You've two inputs fname and lname, the `:eq` will select them by index, try to add `e.preventDefault()` just after `$("#edit").click(function (e) {`

Comment: Thanks, I meant to add that earlier, still no luck though, throwing error: `Cannot read property 'find' of undefined`

Comment: Ok try `var parent_form = $('#regForm');` or `var parent_form = $(this).closest('form');` instead of `var parent_form = $(this.form);`

Comment: Still no difference, I think something else is broken but no errors so can't figure it out, my edit submit handler needs work.

Comment: It is now turning all entries into one long string with slashes, and the second time it added an empty array to the second booking.. I've probably written it wrong.